# How to replace SCSS files with Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

Angular CLI provides the possibility to [replace files](https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-target-specific-file-replacements) when building the project.
I would like to use this functionality to replace a SCSS file with default styling, with a SCSS file that contains customer specific CSS.

But Angular CLI seems not to replace the SCSS files. How could I achieve this?

---

What I have tried:

**environment.default.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  name: 'default'
};
```

**environment.special.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  name: 'special'
};
```

**default/_scss-config.scss**

```
@debug ('default'); // gets called but should never be called
```

**special/_scss-config.scss**

```
@debug ('special'); // never gets called
```

**angular.json** (only relevant parts)

```
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "fileReplacements": [
          {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.default.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.special.ts"
          },
          {
            "replace": "src/scss/default/_scss-config.scss",
            "with": "src/scss/special/_scss-config.scss"
          }
        ],
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            "src/scss/default"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**main.ts**

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment.default';

console.log(environment.name); // 'special' --> replacement works!
```

---

**Result:**
File replacement for `.ts` files works, but not for `.scss` files, as the special debug statment never gets called, but the default does, even the file should have been repalced.

Comment: Show us the commands you've tried

Comment: @jo_va I think I already found the answer, but I added an minimal example. If you know a way to make this work, I would be happy to accept your answer.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Angular.io states that:

> The main CLI configuration file, angular.json, [...] allows you to replace **any file** with a target-specific version of that file.

This is in fact the vision, but according to [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11451), this is not true for now.
It seems up till now, only `.ts` and `.html` files are supported.

Therefore, currently the answer to the question is no, **it is yet not possible to replace SCSS files.**

**But there is a workaround (see below).**

---

**Update Jan-2021:** Still doesn't work. Tested with *Angular 11.0.9*.

**TLDR:**

- Angular 11.x now errors on unsupported file types if you try to use the file replacement feature
  (the workaround described below still works, as it doesn't use the file replacement feature)
- It only has file replacement support for the following types: `.cjs`, `.js`, `.json`, `.mjs` and, `.ts`

**Background:**
It seems the inital statement in the documentaion to support all file types was wrong. With Angular 11 a check was introduced, to error on unsupported file types.

[fix(@angular-devkit/build-angular): add validation to fileReplacement…](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/424af2860260b9e19df9d82940b9f088ea474b95)

> fileReplacement is meant to replace compilation source files (JavaScript or TypeScript) with other compilation source files in the build. With this change we add validation to fail the build when the files have unsupported extensions.

So with Angular 11 two things changed. At first you have to use `src` and `replaceWith` instead of `replace` and `with`. Though this doesn't help as you will get `Data path ".fileReplacements[1].replace" should match pattern "\.(([cm]?j|t)sx?|json)$".`, if you use [unsupported file types](https://regex101.com/r/bjukt4/1) like `.scss`.

---

**Update Feb-2020**: Still doesn't work. Tested with *Angular 9.0.0*.

---

**But there is a workaround:**
You can use different configurations in `angular.json` to achieve the same goal  - replacing a SCSS file.

**folder structure:**

```
src/
    scss/
        default/
            _scss-config.scss
        special/
             _scss-config.scss
```

**src/scss/default/scss-config.scss**

```
body { background-color: blue; }
```

**src/scss/special/scss-config.scss**

```
body { background-color: red; }
```

**angular.json**

```
<!-- language: lang-json -->

{
  [...]
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "options": {
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            "src/scss/default"
          ]
        }
      },
      "configurations": {
        "default": {
          "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
            "includePaths": [
              "src/scss/default/"
            ]
          }
        },
        "special": {
          "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
            "includePaths": [
              "src/scss/special/"
            ]
          }
        }
      }      
    },
    "serve": {
      "configurations": {
        "default": {
          "browserTarget": "angular-scss-replacement:build:default"
        },
        "special": {
          "browserTarget": "angular-scss-replacement:build:special"
        }
      }
    }     
    [...]      
  }
}
```

**style.scss or component.scss**

```
@import 'scss-config';

/* use your SCSS variables and stuff as you normally would */
```

*Note that you mustn't include the `_` (underscore) from the filename in the import statement

(for more details read the [Partials section](https://sass-lang.com/guide))*

**How to use it:**

```
// 'ng serve'-command uses default configuration as defined in angular.json > build 
ng serve

// default config creates blue background
ng serve --configuration=default


// specail config create red background
ng serve -c=special
```

*(This solution is from the thread mentioned above - thx to [richardtreier](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11451#issuecomment-424715627))*

---

**Drawbacks of this approach:**

- It forces you to have a specific folder structure to separate your different SCSS configurations
- It might force you to move those folders out of your normal folder structure.
  For example, `"includePaths": ["src/scss"]` won't work with the folder structure mentioned above, since the SCSS configs can't be loaded separately.

Comment: @OrangeDog: I tried the above approach in Angular 11 app and it is not working. Were you able to get it working in latest Angular 11 apps?

Comment: @suvenk no, 11 and 8 are different numbers

Comment: @OrangeDog: Ya I know. Do you know if there is any other way to achieve this in Angular 11 apps?

Comment: Yes this still works in ng11 for me. I updated the answer to reflect the changes regarding file replacements in ng11, but since the workaround doesn't use the feature it is no problem.

Comment: Its working for ng serve but not ng build :(

Comment: Did you build the correct configuration (for the above example it would be `ng build -c special`)? Works fine for me. Otherwise you may consider opening a separate question with some more details.

Comment: I moved all my styles from `src/assets/scss` to `src/assets/scss/default` and `src/assets/scss/special`, but now I get an error that `src/assets/scss/bootstrap.scss` is not found. Does this solution also replace `filename.scss` without the leading _ ?

Comment: This "solution" (I guess you are refering to the workaround) doesn't replace anything. As said it doesn't use the Angular file replacement feature, this is the reason it works for SCSS files. It might be necessary to put some files outside the `/default` and `/special` folders. Another guess is, that you either screwed up the imports by creating the new folder structure or you still try to use Angualr file replacements feature, which in some Angular versions, doesn't care about the file name or extension. That said, it might need an extra question to really understand whats the problem here.

Comment: I am using Angular 13 and I applied your approach but inside the environment folder and works fine for, appreciate your help