# Theming Angular Apps and Libraries with Bootstrap and sass

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I am using a MonoRepo approach for building customer Apps. All of my logic like components are in several Angular libraries. For every customer I will have a different App to make some configuration in it and provide the layout the customer wants. Furthermore in each customer App I would like to overwrite bootstraps theme-colors. In the libraries/components I would like to access the theme-colors.

Here is the problem:
In the components.scss files in my libraries I cant import variables.scss neither from bootstrap (because then I would have the default colors) nor from my app (because then I would have the colors of one specific customer in all my library components).

How can I solve the problem to style every app individually using scss?

Comment: Bootstrap utilizes css variables (check :root) and therefore you can simply overrite them and thus have themed most of the components which can be changed on fly by changing css variable

Comment: @Sergey I know but it seems as bootstrap doesn´t want to change to css variables at all. So I don´t know how reliable this is. See this Github discussion: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/26596

Comment: Have you thought about splitting the theme-variables in another file? Then you can first include the global styles and include the theme variables from a dynamic customer url. Or, create the components with only utility classes and style those for each customer.

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest you trying [this option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54724272/how-to-replace-scss-files-with-angular-cli) discussed on StackOverflow.
It utilizes includePaths approach instead of fileReplacements (which was my first thought but for now Angular doesn't work with SCSS).

I believe that you can build using different configuration and replace SCSS variables file depending on a project you build. Unfortunately this approach requires polluting angular.json file with tons of configurations for each project that requires its own styling.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don´t feel like I am polluting my angular.json since I just add the stylePreprocessorOptions to my 'projectName'->architect->build->options property. By this it is applied to everything I do, like ng serve or ng build unless I overwrite it in my serve options.

Comment: Glad it helped you